# Is there an imaging library that can make you look thinner?

Tags: image-manipulation, photoshop, imaging

Very odd question, I know, but this is a problem a potential client handed me today.

We assume we have a full length photo of a person. We want to generate a thinner image of that user. Obviously, one way would just be to compress the width of the image but that would result in various distortions that wouldn't be realistic.

I'd like to keep this an open-source implementation so if anybody knows of a library that can identify certain parts of the body and slim each in a way that is most realistic, I'd like to know.

This is obviously something that could be done by hand but we need a solution that works without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [seam-carving algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving). The algorithm is very simple to implement and has many such implmentations online. [Seems like ImageMagick has it too](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#liquid-rescale) - called "Liquid Rescale".

Answer (score 0):

I assume that already the detection of bodyparts in photos is a challenge too hard for algorithms, unless the photos are all very similar (e.g. same background, same pose, etc.)

I have once played around developing algorithms for skin smoothing. I was able to detect skin areas pretty well by converting colors to the LAB space and selecting pixels similar to skin sample colors learnt with a support vector machine from various sample images. Once you have that, you could run something like a liquify-contract algorithm for slimming.

I wouldn't expect satisfying results though unless you spend huge amounts of time on this.

Comment: I've seen something that just applies a bi-concave distortion on the image between the neck and feet. I'm drifting toward opencv and doing that at the moment because (as ever) I don't have a million man-hours to spent on, what's essentially just a marketing tool.